# How to add the value in string and go to next letter?

Tags: python, string, if-statement

Two people participate in competition . There will be one easy, difficult and medium question

```
Difficulty  Score
   E             1
   M             3
   H             5
```

User will enter two strings e and b , and function should find out greater scores or tie.

My code is:

```
def winner(e, b):
    sume = 0
    sumb =0
    highest = 0
    x = False
    for i in (range(len(erica))):
        if (erica[i] =='E'):
            sume +=1
            x = True
        elif (erica[i] =='M'):
            sume = sume+3
            x = True
        elif (erica[i] =='H'):
            sume +=5
            x = True
        return sume

if __name__ == '__main__':
    erica = input()
    bob = str(input())

print(winner(e,b))
```

When I enter `HEM` for `e`, it should give `9` but it only gives `5`.

Comment: Not the solution to your problem, but I suggest using correct variables: you should be passing `erica` and `bob` to `winner`, and then using `e` and `b` inside `winner`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the return statement indentation. Try Below.

Also, you are not passing the correct variables.

```
def winner(e, b):
    sume = 0
    sumb =0
    highest = 0
    x = False
    for i in (range(len(e))):
        if (e[i] =='E'):
            sume +=1
            x = True
        elif (e[i] =='M'):
            sume = sume+3
            x = True
        elif (e[i] =='H'):
            sume +=5
            x = True
    return sume
if __name__ == '__main__':
    e = input()
    b = str(input())
print(winner(e,b))
```

Comment: and the `print()` should be indented inside the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def winner(e, b):
    sume = 0
    sumb =0
    highest = 0
    for i in (range(len(e))):
        if (e[i] =='E'):
            sume +=1
        elif (e[i] =='M'):
            sume = sume+3
        elif (e[i] =='H'):
            sume +=5
    for i in (range(len(b))):
        if (b[i] =='E'):
            sumb +=1
        elif (b[i] =='M'):
            sumb = sumb+3
        elif (b[i] =='H'):
            sumb +=5
    if(sume>sumb):
        return "Erica"
    else:
        return "Bob"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    e = input()
    b = str(input())
    print(winner(e,b))
```